# How to add or append a parameter for class which extends Action.Simple

Tags: playframework

I have written SecuredAction class which extends Action.Simple.

In few method i have added as below before the method

```
  @With(SecuredAction.class)
```

Now i want to sent some parameters along with the above.

Can someone help me please on how to pass parameter or sent parameter ????

I want to retrieve the passed parameter in the class which extends Action.Simple

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining [custom action annotations](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaActionsComposition#Defining-custom-action-annotations).

```
@With(SecureAction.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MySecureAnnotation{
    // define your parameters here
    boolean myParam() default true;
}
```

You can then annotate your controllers and action methods with this annotation instead and set the parameters.

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
     @MySecureAnnotation(myParam = false)
     public Result foo() {
         return ok();
     }

     @MySecureAnnotation(myParam = true)
     public Result bar() {
         return notFound();
     }
}
```

Please note that you can only provide compile time values via annotation parameters.